# Cutting something into smaller things

Tags: grammar

I was surfing around when I came across this sentence:

> She cuts the cake into eighths.

Is that a grammatically correct way to phrase it? Or is it "cut into eight"?

Comment: Whatever you choose.  Generally larger numbers are "cut into <number>", i.e. "Cut this cake into twelve" rather than "Cut this cake into twelfths", but both are acceptable.

Comment: There is a slight difference. If the cake is cut into eighths, then you would assume eight pieces of equal size. Whereas a cake cut into eight, simply states there are eight pieces (which could be of varying sizes).